# How to annotate in 2 decimal places using Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to create a heatmap displaying correlation coefficient values. I'm quite new at this, but the code below would annotate in multiple decimal places, whereas i'm trying to narrow down to 2 d.p.

Does anyone have experience with this?

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns


style.use('ggplot')

def visualize_data():
    df = pd.read_csv('sti_joined.csv')
    df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    df_corr = df.pct_change().corr()

    print(df_corr.head())

    data = df_corr.values
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

    # heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlGn'))
    heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.cm.RdYlGn)
    fig.colorbar(heatmap)
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[0]) + 0.5, minor=False)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[1]) + 0.5, minor=False)
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    ax.xaxis.tick_top()

    for y in range(data.shape[0]):
        for x in range(data.shape[1]):
            plt.text(x + 0.5, y + 0.5, '%.4f' % data[y, x],
                     horizontalalignment='center',
                     verticalalignment='center',
                     )

    column_labels = df_corr.columns
    row_labels = df_corr.index

    ax.set_xticklabels(column_labels)
    ax.set_yticklabels(row_labels)
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    heatmap.set_clim(-1,1)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

visualize_data()
```

Comment: You could use [seaborn's heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html): `sns.heatmap(..., fmt='%.2f')`.

Comment: Thank you! yes i managed to do it with seaborn

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `'%.4f' % data[y, x]`, you can try using something like

```
'{0:.2f}'.format(data[y,x])
```